# How do I display print_r on different lines?

Tags: php

When I run the following code:

```
echo $_POST['zipcode'];

print_r($lookup->query($_POST['zipcode']));

?>
```

the results are concatenated on one line like so: `10952Array`.

How can I get it to display on separate lines, like so:

```
08701
Array
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You might need to add a linebreak:

```
echo $_POST['zipcode'] . '<br/>';
```

If you wish to add breaks between print_r() statements:

```
print_r($latitude); 
echo '<br/>';
print_r($longitude);
```

Comment: And when it's two print_r statements how do I add the linebreak?
    print_r($latitude);
    print_r($longitude);

Comment: You can add an extra echo '<br/>' in between the print_r() statements. See edit.

Answer (score 21):

to break line with print_r:

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($lookup->query($_POST['zipcode']));
echo "</pre>";
```

The  element will format it with any pre-existing formatting, so \n will turn into a new line, returned lines (when you press return/enter) will also turn into new lines.

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre is a really useful read.

Answer (score 9):

If this is what your browser displays:

```
Array ( [locus] => MK611812 [version] => MK611812.1 [id] => 1588040742 )
```

And this is what you want:

```
Array
(
    [locus] => MK611812
    [version] => MK611812.1
    [id] => 1588040742
)
```

the easy solution is to add the the `<pre>` format to your code that prints the array:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I generally include the following function with all of my PHP:

The problem occurs because line breaks are not normally shown in HTML output. The trick is to wrap the output inside a `pre` element:

```
function printr($data) {
    echo sprintf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($data,true));
}
```

`print_r(…, true)` returns the output without (yet) displaying it. From here it is inserted into the string using the `printf` function.

Comment: Lovely solution. Thank you.

Comment: Here I contribute with some classic black and green console styling. Enclose the `<pre>` tag with `<div>` tag, and add the following rule to your CSS: `pre { padding: 1em; background-color: #000000; color: #08FF08; }`

Answer (score 2):

Just echo these : `echo $_POST['zipcode']."<br/>";`